# Google Analytics: track scroll depth in pixels - the simple way

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I found a site that explains how to generate scroll depth reports: [here](http://mybrainlounge.wordpress.com/2014/04/06/google-analytics-tracking-scroll-depth-the-easy-way/)
It uses really small code (usually they are huge):

```
window.onbeforeunload = scrollExit;
function scrollExit()
{
    bottom = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Scroll Depth', 'Pixel Depth', '', bottom]);
}
});
```

and that is it. but only problem is that it is not working :D as i see by the comments author said that it is not just simple copy/paste code, so i would like to know what else do i need to add so it works?

BTW as author said it should work with Classic and Universal Analytics, so:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Scroll Depth', 'Pixel Depth', '', bottom]);
```

or

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Scroll Depth', 'Pixel Depth', bottom);
```

should both work

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you would need to include jQuery into your page for this to work. And if you do that you might as well use one of the many scroll depth plugins for jQuery (the reason they are huge is that they take care of possible edge cases whereas "simple code" usually requires you to live in an ideal universe to work. For a start unload events are not particularly reliable. Also if you already have dumped jQuery into your site some more lines for a plugin do not make that much of a problem, and the code you will actually have to write yourself is much smaller, usually just one line to invoke the plugin).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

  var scrolltrigger0 = 1; 
var scrolltrigger25 = 1; 
var scrolltrigger50 = 1; 
var scrolltrigger75 = 1; 
var scrolltrigger100 = 1; 

jQuery(window).scroll(function(){ 
var wintop = jQuery(window).scrollTop(), 
docheight = jQuery(document).height(), 
winheight = jQuery(window).height(); 
var scroll = Math.round((wintop/(docheight-winheight))*100);
var pathName=window.location.pathname;

 if(scroll > 22 && scroll < 27 && scrolltrigger25){
    ga('my_tracker.send', 'event', 'scroll depth', 'percentage', '25%');
       console.log('25');

scrolltrigger25 = 0;
 }
  if(scroll > 47 && scroll < 53 && scrolltrigger50){
    ga('my_tracker.send', 'event', 'scroll depth', 'percentage', '50%');
     console.log('50');
 scrolltrigger50 = 0;
  }
   if(scroll > 73 && scroll < 78 && scrolltrigger75){
    ga('my_tracker.send', 'event', 'scroll depth', 'percentage', '75%');
   console.log('75');
   scrolltrigger75 = 0;


   }
     if(scroll===100 && scrolltrigger100){
    ga('my_tracker.send', 'event','scroll depth', 'percentage', '100%');
    console.log('100');
 scrolltrigger100 = 0;


  }

 });

   </script>
```

This will perfectly work for scroll depth tracking through GTM..cheers

my_tracker is a variable where you store your trackerid.ex-UA-234234234.